# AWS Lex v2 bot not showing more than 3 cards when integrating it with facebook messenger

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, facebook-chatbot

I have created a new intent in AWS Lex v2 where I have to show the user his entered slot initial responses in term of cards. The options that I have to show him are a total of 6, but when I am testing it on Facebook messenger it is only showing at most 3 cards at a time. This is because Facebook doesn't allows to show more than 3 cards at a time. Help me handle this issue to show all the necessary information that I require to show the user.

I tried doing it like I am showing the first two cards and then showing the text on the third card text as others. And the value of that third card is referencing to a new intent which shows the next 2 options on the card. And then repeating the same step to create another intent and showing the remaining responses. I don't think that this is the best possible option to handle a scenario like this.

Please guide !

Comment: Your suggested approach could work provided you have a Lambda function backing it up to cycle through the values and build up the appropriate card responses.
Offhand, I would imagine it should be possible to show all three cards with the first 3 of the options and then using a quick reply after the cards with the value of 'show more' to show the remaining values. 'show more' would need to trigger a slot in your new intent to keep the user in the same context.